# adding www in URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have got this URL `http://mysite.com/blog/` and I want to convert it to `http://www.mysite.com/blog/`

I am trying:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

I tried putting it first in root and then in blog directory but didn't work.

There is one more condition. I don't want any other urls to be changed as they have already been modified from `http://www.mysite.com/` to `http://www.shop.mysite.com/`. I just want the urls with `/blog` to be appened with `www` and the blog has been developed in wordpress.

Any help would be appreciated.

**This is another solution that I tried and it causes a redirection loop**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the second solution does work. you just need to put htaccess at root. So the final solution for my problem was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```